# Find value in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

```
taglist = [{:name=>"Daniel_Xu_Forever", :tag=>["helo", "world"]},   
{:name=>"kcuf", :tag=>["hhe"]},  
{:name=>"fine", :tag=>[]},   
{:name=>"how hare you", :tag=>[]},  
{:name=>"heki", :tag=>["1", "2", "3"]}, 
{:name=>"railsgirls", :tag=>[]},  
{:name=>"_byoy", :tag=>[]},   
{:name=>"ajha", :tag=>[]},  
{:name=>"nimei", :tag=>[]}]
```

How to get specified name's tag from taglist

For example , I want to extract user `"fine"`'s tag?

Could this be achieved without `do` iterator?

Comment: does it have to be an array of hashes?

Comment: if not, use `taglist = {:kcuf => ["hhe"], :fine => [] ...}`

Comment: Yes, It must be an array of hashes!

Comment: What's wrong with iteration using a block?

Answer (score 4):

This will return the contents of the `:tag` key for any users name which `== 'fine'`

```
taglist.select { |x| x[:name] == 'fine' }.map { |u| u[:tag] }
```

First you select out only the users you are interested with [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

And then use [`.map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to collect an array of only what you want.

In this case the end result will be: `[]`

Comment: "Could this be achieved without `do` iterator?" Yeah, an absurd condition but it is part of the "question".

Comment: lol, early sunday morning without my glasses... didn't even read that.

Comment: I guess you missed the "solve this problem using Ruby but don't use Ruby" part of the question too :) I wonder if JSON encoding the hash and feeding it to a Python script using `%x[...]` would qualify as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Is `do` really an iterator?

```
taglist.find{|tl| tl[:name] == 'fine'}[:tag]
```

Just to be silly how about:

```
eval taglist.to_s[/:name=>"fine", :tag=>(.*?)}/, 1]
#=> []
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be done without a loop.

And even if you find a solution where your code avoids a loop, for sure the library function that you're calling will include a loop. Finding an element in an array requires a loop. Period.

For example, take this (contrived) example

```
  pattern = "fine"
  def pattern.===(h); self == h[:name]; end
  taglist.grep(pattern)
```

which does not seem to use a loop, but calls `grep` which is implemented using a loop.

Or another, equally contrived, example

```
  class Hash; def method_missing(sym); self[sym]; end; end
  taglist.group_by(&:name)["fine"]
```

which again does seem to call `group_by` without a loop, but actually it does.

So the answer is, no.

Answer (score 0):

So my first answer missed the no `do` rule.
Here is an answer that doesn't use a `do` block.

```
i=0
begin
  if taglist[i][:name] == 'fine'
    tag = taglist[i][:tag]
    break
  end
  i+=1
end while i < taglist.length - 0
```

Technically I think this is still using a block. But probably satisfies the restriction.

Comment: Hmm, a `while` has an implicit `do` when you think about it.

Comment: Yeah it does... I can't think of any iterator that doesn't take a block.. :/